# Prevent altering X-Forwarded-For

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, http-headers

We have a simple api that is hosted in azure vm, we have included an application gateway. And the application works fine, until we require to log the clients ip because we have to determine the location of our clients via ipstack.

I have added this code in our HomeController

```
var ip = string.Empty;

if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-For"))
{
    ip = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works fine, until I decided to use Postman to call the api and added the X-Forwarded-For in the request.

[image: postman]
[image: fake ip injected]

I have included the header as a result in our api just to check and...

```
"X-Forwarded-For": "<script>alert('test');</script>,192.168.0.1", //masked my real Ip

"X-Forwarded-For": "0.0.0.0,192.168.0.1" //fake ip (0.0.0.0)
```

Is there anyway to prevent this?

I have included the below code in startup.cs but still no luck.

```
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(c =>
            {
                //c.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
                //c.ForwardLimit = 1;
                //c.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.0"));
                c.ForwardedForHeaderName = "X-Forwarded-For-My-Custom-Header-Name";
            });
```

Comment: XSS attack? URLencode? Is that what you're asking? I'm not quite sure - are you trying to prevent postman x-forwarded-for specifying JS?

Comment: Not XSS attack, just only to prevent or to modify or alter the header

Comment: As you said it can be done on the client-side using Postman, apart from some lookup validation table to reject invalid headers I don't see how you can circumvent x-forwarded-for modifications . And why bother? What's the crux of this question?

Comment: @JeremyThompson, clients can manipulate their ip addresses, when using the api. we want to prevent it. instead we get the real ip of the clients, we can get anything if they modify intentionally the x-forwarded-for.